# Is this thing a value quantale?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, lattice-orders

I am currently trying to understand R. C. Flagg's "Quantales and continuity spaces".

However I am struggling a bit with his definitions and would like to have a good simple (but not too simple) example of a value quantale. Hence my question:

Let 
$$P=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,\infty]\}$$
be equipped with a usual pointwise order:
$$f\leq_P g\quad\text{ iff }\quad \forall x \ \ \ f(x)\leq g(x),$$
and pointwise addition:
$$(f+_Pg)(x):=f(x)+g(x).$$
($[0,1]$ and $[0,\infty]$ are considered with their usual orders and addition operations.)

Is $(P,\leq_P,+_P)$ a value quantale?

$\bf{Here\ is\ a\ more\ general\ question:}$
suppose that we have a family $\{P_j\}_{j\in J}$ of value quantales. Is their Cartesian product $\prod_{j\in J}P_j$ equipped with usual coordinate-wise order and coordinate-wise operation a value quantale?

Comment: Could you recite the definition of "value quantale"? I don't know it and google doesn't either...

Comment: @AlexR A value quantale is a set equipped with both order structure and a monoid structure such that these structures are in a suitable way compatible with each other (for example, among other properties, the bottom element of a lattice induced by the chosen order is an identity element of  the monoid structure). All axioms of a value quantale are quite complicated so I recommend you simply check the mentioned paper by R. C. Flagg.

Comment: The mathscinet review of this paper also contains a complete definition.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I'll look into it later when I have some spare time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, though it meets most of the requirements. Indeed, most of the requirements are clear; only those involving the well above relation relation are not. It is true that $\langle P,\le_P\rangle$ is completely distributive.

Let $f,g\in P$ with $f<_Pg$. If there is an $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=g(x)$, for each $n\in\Bbb N$ define

$$h_n:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]:t\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(t)+2^{-n},&\text{if }t=x\\
f(t),&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and let $S=\{h_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$; then $\bigwedge S=f$, but $g(x)=f(x)<f(x)+2^{-n}=h_n(x)$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, so $h_n\not\le_P g$, and hence $f\not\prec g$.

If $g(x)>f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, let $A=\{x\in[0,1]:g(x)\ne\infty\}$. Assume for now that $|A|\ge 2$, and let $\varphi:[0,1]\times\Bbb N\to A$ be any surjection such that for each $\langle x,n\rangle\in[0,1]\times\Bbb N$, $\varphi(\langle x,n\rangle)\ne x$. For $\langle x,n\rangle\in[0,1]\times\Bbb N$ define

$$h_{\langle x,n\rangle}:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]:t\mapsto\begin{cases}
f(x)+2^{-n},&\text{if }t=x\\
g(t)+1,&\text{if }t=\varphi(\langle x,n\rangle)\\
f(t),&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

and let $S=\{h_{\langle x,n\rangle}:\langle x,n\rangle\in[0,1]\times\Bbb N\}$. Then $\bigwedge S=f$, and $g\big(\varphi(\langle x,n\rangle)\big)<h_{\langle x,n\rangle}\big(\varphi(\langle x,n\rangle)\big)$ for each $\langle x,n\rangle\in[0,1]\times\Bbb N$, so again $f\not\prec g$.

Thus, if $f\prec g$, there can be at most one $x\in[0,1]$ such that $g(x)\ne\infty$, and if there is such a point $x$, then $g(x)>f(x)$.

Conversely, it’s not hard to check that

- $f\prec g$ if there is an $x\in[0,1]$ such that $g(t)=\infty$ for $t\in[0,1]\setminus\{x\}$, and $f(x)<g(x)$; and
- if $\mathbf{1}_P\in P$ is defined by $\mathbf{1}_P(t)=\infty$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, then $\mathbf{1}_P\prec\mathbf{1}_P$.

From this it follows easily that $f=\bigwedge\{g\in P:f\prec g\}$ for all $f\in P$ and hence that $\langle P,\le_P\rangle$ is completely distributive.

Now let $\mathbf{0}_P$ be defined by $\mathbf{0}_P(t)=0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$; to show that $\langle P,\le_P,+_P\rangle$ is a value quantale we would have to show that if $\mathbf{0}_P\prec f,g\in P$, then $\mathbf{0}_P\prec f\land g$. Unfortunately, this need not be true. Let

$$f:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]:t\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }t=0\\
\infty,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and

$$g:[0,1]\to[0,\infty]:t\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }t=1\\
\infty,&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

We’ve just seen that $\mathbf{0}_P\prec f,g$, but $(f\land g)(t)<\infty$ for both $t=0$ and $t=1$, so $\mathbf{0}_P\not\prec f\land g$.

Comment: Dear @Brian, thank you for your answer. I have two more questions and I feel you might be able to help me. First one: if we keep coordinate-wise order $\leq$ and coordinate-wise addition $+$ is it possible that for a (nontrivial) subset $M\subset P$ $(M,\leq,+)$ is a value quantale (maybe $M$ consisting of non-decreasing functions will be good?)? And second question: Kopperman and Flagg have proved that every topology comes from generalized metric (with values in a value quantale instead of nonnegative numbers). This result seem to be very powerful.

Comment: How big is its impact on topology and "continuous mathematics"? I don't see this theorem being used (or even mentioned) often. Is this theorem just simply forgotten or the idea that every topological space is sort of a metric space (with generalized metric) isn't as powerful as it seems?

Comment: @Godot: You’re welcome. My first reaction is that the example probably can’t be salvaged by passing to a subset of $P$, but I’ll have to think about it. I’m not sure that I can answer the second question properly: this is only the second time that I’ve encountered value quantales, and the first time was also here at MSE. They came along after I had largely stopped doing research, and they tend to be combined with category theory, for which I have no taste at all. I have a vague impression that they are of some importance in theoretical computer science, but my knowledge of the field is far ...

Comment: ... too superficial for that to mean much. My guess – and it *is* just a guess, since I’m not familiar with the proof of the theorem – is that the result is not likely to be useful in answering the kinds of questions that I think of as being characteristic of general and set-theoretic topology.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion on the subject matter. Just to add few bits of information to our discussion: in his paper Flagg gives a class of examples of value quantales with underlying sets consisting of nondecreasing functions (they are distance distribution functions as used in probabilistic metric spaces theory). However the order used in those spaces is the reversed point-wise order and operation is certainly not point-wise additions (so called triangle functions are used). So these value quantales are quite close to what I wanted, but not exactly. Best regards.